# Hosting XNA in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xna, embed

I want to create a Map Editor application in WPF, and I'm using XNA as the game engine.

I followed several tutorials to embed my XNA game into a WPF application, but I couldn't get working any of them.

I found a tutorial which is pretty simple here: (It's in french but all the code is here)
http://remember.waralan.fr/?p=497

But when I compile, here's my error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the source code and it seems to be working. You just have to check the associated resource files like "white.xnb" that is not included. Just don't use it (comment usage lines in code) or use your own custom resources in content folder.

Supposed file location in build directory is: "**Content / white.xnb**"

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem!
Thank you!